# .htaccess - redirecting www and non-www subfolder to same location

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to forward all the content in subfolders to a respective root.com/folder on my root server.

I've successfully used the code below to forward country.root.com to the root.com/folder, however when I type is www.country.root.com into the web browser - it does not redirect (I've tried making it work but nothing happens - this is the code I'm back to).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^uk\.domain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/uk$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Have been messing around with this for a while. Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please use only real values. Talking of country.root.com and having uk.domain.com in your rule only adds considerable confusion.

Comment: And also make sure that your `code` is displayed as-is, e.g. newlines do show as newlines. You can write `code` by quoting with backticks (\`code\`) or by indenting whole paragraphs by at least 4 spaces.

Comment: Should `www.uk.domain.com` redirect to the same folder as `uk.domain.com` already does? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)uk.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/uk$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This should help you, works for me.

Comment: If you like my answer, you can accept it by using ✔ on the left.

Comment: Nitpick: Probably `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\.|^)uk.domain.com` is better suited because it wouldn't match `suk.domain.com` (untested, might have to correct the escaping to get the regex right)